# GWT htmlDialogBox: How to set the size to wider width

Tags: gwt

I want to resize my htmlDialogBox to wider width. This is what I have now. Half of my html is cut off. I want to display the entire html in the htmlDialogBox.

GWT version:         2.8.0-SNAPSHOT

```
    verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    verticalPanel.setSpacing(0);

    setWidget(verticalPanel);
    verticalPanel.setSize("100%","100%");
    scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
    verticalPanel.add(scrollPanel);

    htmlDialogBox = new HTML();
    verticalPanel.add(htmlDialogBox);
    scrollPanel.setWidget(htmlDialogBox);

    htmlDialogBox.setSize("100%", "100%");
    htmlDialogBox.setHTML(html);
    setGlassEnabled(true);
    setAnimationEnabled(true);
    setPopupPosition(ClientUtils.DIALOG_X_POSITION,ClientUtils.DIALOG_Y_POSITION);
    show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I find my own answer.

change setAnimationEnabled(true); to setAnimationEnabled(false);